# Google Blogger Website CName and/or Text File Issues

Tags: google, dns, subdomain, blogger, cname

I have a blogger Blog website and I would like to have it show up on my company website. I have read a couple articles out there on how to do it. A hand full of them talk about using FTP which is old and no longer available. However, I am trying to following along with this one:

http://www.infinite42.com/small-business/integrate-blogger-blog-website

Which seems pretty easy but I am having a problem getting Google to Verify the DNS CName or Text Record that I created on my Windows 2007 Server. Do I need to create this record at the registrar level. Right now the domain is setup at the registrar to point the www record to my server where on my server I tried the Txt Record and the CName Record with no luck in DNS.

Here are the Google instructions for creating a CName file record in DNS:

Follow the steps below to create a DNS (Domain Name System) record that proves to Google that you own the domain.

Add the CNAME record below to the DNS configuration for abc.com. CNAME Label / Host: CNAME Destination / Target:

Click Verify below. When Google finds this DNS record, we'll make you a verified owner of the domain. (Note: DNS changes may take some time. If we don't find the record immediately, we'll check for it periodically.) To stay verified, don't remove the DNS record, even after verification succeeds.

Here is the link to do it with a CName:

http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2012/08/domain-verification-using-cname-records.html

When I go to add my CName record on my server's DNS the only two fields available are Alias Name and Fully Qualified Domain Name. How am I suppose to create this record can someone please tell me?

Thanks,

Frank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Do I need to create this record at the registra level?

You can go through whichever hosting company, registrar company or control panel that manages your domain's DNS settings. The best thing to do is to associate a sub-domain with the blog.

How you do this depends on your hosting plan etc. If I was doing it with my personal website, then I would go into my control panel and create a new CName record to send requests to blog.mydomain.com to the google blog address.

2) When I go to add my CName record on my server's DNS the only two fields available are Alias Name and Fully Qualified Domain Name. How am I suppose to create this record can someone please tell me?

You can add an alias name (CName means canonical name, and is the same as an alias) to your server and it may resolve the domain name correctly. Personally I'd keep all of my DNS settings in one place as it simplifies the management, but you're welcome to try it that way if you wish.

I hope this helps.

---

[Google DNS Instructionsfor Blogger Integration](http://support.google.com/blogger/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=58317)

Basically all you have to do is create a CName (or alias) record for blog.mydomain.com and have it forward on ghs.google.com.

You then need to change your blogger settings to use your domain blog.mydomain.com. Google then handles the rest. The link above has complete walkthroughs for multiple hosting / registrar companies.

Comment: thank you for the reply. Anwser to questions 1. The domain name is registered with Network Solutions. The IT of the domain name which is not me setup a record to point www to my server. Because he has an exchange box as well with that domain. So I have DNS on my server to that is handling the www for the website. I wanted to know if I create a CName on my server will it work with Google because the entire domain isn't pointing at my server just the www.

Comment: Question 2: Google provides info for the Cname which is for example: Name, Label, or Host field = ABC and then Destination, Target, or Points To field = 123. However when I create a CName it only has a field for Alias and Fully Qualified Domain name. So I don't know how to take a value of ABC and 123 and create a CName for it so Google can validate it.

Comment: BTW I am creating the CName in MS Windows Server 2008 DNS.

Comment: @FrancisGibbons I'm afraid that the change has to be made at the higher level DNS setting, so you need to get the domain IT manager to change the main DNS records. And I've modified my answer to answer your question about the DNS record required.

Comment: Thank you, Okay so I will have him create the record in Network Solutions and then if I create a sub such as blog.mywebsite.com that should work fine then correct?

Comment: @FrankG. You could do it that way, yes. blog.mydomain.com would forward to your server which would forward to the google website. You could also just get the main DNS record to forward to google, it's up to you.

Comment: But if I setup a CName in my DNS called blog and point it at ghs.google.com and have the IT guy put the info google need to verify the domain will this setup work? Thanks again!

Comment: @FrankG. Yes & yes. However, for the domain name verification I would just use google's ftp verification - it's easier. You just upload a text file containing a verification code you get from google to your website's root directory. And I would just have the IT guy point the blog.domain.com CName record at ghs.google.com. It cuts out the extra DNS record, but I'd expect your way to work too - so it's up to you.

Comment: Scott, I didn't see that as an option. The only option is to Add the TXT record below to the DNS configuration for mywebsite.com or create a CName record. Do you know where I can find that option? Thanks again for your help!!

Comment: Perhaps I've misunderstood your question, but you want to create a CName record. All you need to do is create a CName record with a host name / alias of 'blog' and a value of 'ghs.google.com'. I am going to sleep now, but I will respond to any other questions you have in the morning, so feel free to ask.

Comment: Hey Paul, thank you again very much. I am going to give it a try and see how things go. I will keep you post once I get there! Thanks again!!